# ROR request an action to get a range of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, range, param

How would I create an action that takes in parameters to limit search results? This would be out of my Posts model

Posts_controller:

`def getOneThrougTen`

params[firstNum] params[secondNum]

return range of some sort?

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve, but if it is displaying search results in chunks, I'll advice you to use the [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) gem!

Comment: will_paginate is apparently not updated for Rails 3 yet, so if you're on Rails 3 and want pagination, try out Kaminari instead

Answer (score 0):

Once you learn the basics of how active record mimics sql calls passing the parameters becomes intuitive.  For example this is how you would create a collection of @posts from your Post model based on a range from a particular column, order the results and limit the number returned.

You can watch the script/server output to see the actual SQL to help understand what is going on and why something doesn't go as planned.

```
@posts=Post.find(:all, :conditions=>["db_column_name between ? and ?", firstNum, secondNum],:order=>"db_column_name ASC", :limit=>10)
```

To actually send and read your params..
In your controller you can read params sent by the view and assign them to variables.  For example you could do.

```
 def getDateRangeandPassItOn
     firstNum=params[:firstNum] 
     ...
```

To actually send them from the view to your controller is different depending on if you are using a fully restful controller such as the one generated in rails scaffoldind.  If all you want is to send them into a non restful method such as "getDateRangeandPassItOn" you would do something like this in your view.

```
<% form_for ({:controller => 'name', :action => "getDateRangeandPassItOn"}) do f%>    
<%f.label :firstNum%> 
<%f.textField :firstNum%>
<%f.submit "submit"%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Rails 3 makes this `Post.where(:db_column_name => firstNum..secondNum).limit(10).all`

Comment: How do i pass in the params to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for pagination type code, you should look at the new capabilities provided with Arel and ActiveRecord in Rails 3. That will allow you to do the following:

```
@posts = Post.all.limit(myLimit).offset(myOffset)
```

or

```
@posts = Post.where(["user_id = ?",myUserId]).limit(myLimit).offset(myOffset).order("created_at desc")
```

etc. etc. Very powerful stuff.